# wordpress, get page list with their thumbnails, but only pages with a certain custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress I am trying to get a page list with their thumbnails, but only pages with a certain custom field. I can get the list, but not their thumbnails. This is what I have so far:

```
 <?php wp_list_pages( 'meta_key=mypagetag&meta_value=crew&depth=2&title_li=&get_the_post_thumbnail=1' );?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`&get_the_post_thumbnail=1` is not a valid argument in [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

what I suggest you doing is add a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) to your `wp_list_pages`

check out [this tuturial](http://badfunproductions.com/create-a-custom-walker-class-to-extend-wp_list_pages/)

Comment: I tried a custom walker and it works great, but I don't know how to select only the pages that have the meta_key and it's value set in the Walker.